# For 1 form $\xi$, $F^{*}(d\xi)=d(F^{*}\xi)$

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry, multivariable-calculus

Let $F:M \to N$ be a mapping of surfaces, and $\xi$ be a function.

I want to show the following identity.

$$F^{*}(d\xi)=d(F^{*}\xi)$$

What I did :

Fix a tangent vector $v$.

$$F^{*}(d\xi)(v)=(d\xi)(F_{*}v)=\frac{d}{dt}(\xi(y(t))_{t=0}$$

where $y(t)=F(\alpha(t)), \alpha'(0)=v$

I used that $y'(t)=F_{*}(\alpha'(t))$.

Next, consider the right term.

$$d(F^{*}\xi)(v)=\frac{d}{dt}(F^{*}\xi)(\alpha(t))_{t=0}=\frac{d}{dt}(\xi(F_{*}\alpha(t))_{t=0}$$

where $\alpha'(0)=v$.

But $y'(0)=F_{*}(\alpha'(0)) \neq \frac{d}{dt}(F_{*}\alpha(t))_{t=0}$.

What is my mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your last equation, what do you mean by $F_* \alpha (t)$?

For a function $\xi$, $F^* \xi = \xi \circ F$.  So you have
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\vert_{t=0} (F^* \xi)(\alpha (t)) = \frac{d}{dt}\vert_{t=0} (\xi \circ F) (\alpha(t)),
$$
which is the same expression at the end of your first line ($\frac{d}{dt}\vert_{t=0} \xi(y(t)$).

Comment: Thanks. I think that I should be familiar with the definition of the forms.